# Bootstrap tile-based list

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, web, tile

I'm making a web app which should list objects gathered from json in a tile-based list (kinda like shopping store), where every tile is a div. What is the best way to do that in Bootstrap ? I'm using Angular and I want to do it with a help from ng-repeat directive. If the number of divs exceed view area, scroll bar should appear.

[This is graphical view, how I want it to look like.](http://postimg.org/image/nhqw687gb/)

What is actually the best way to implement that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regular [bootstrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

The width of the page is 12 units, so divs of width 4 will give you 3 columns. If you keep adding divs with a total width of more than 12, it will be placed in diferent rows.

In the example I gave you, you should get exacly 2 rows with 3 elements in each.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class=container>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="tile in tiles">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-header">
                {{tile.header}}
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                {{tile.body}}
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Something like this maybe? I use `col-sm-4`, that way 3 tiles can be visible in a row. When the screen becomes smaller, then 700-something, it will be layed upon eachother instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstraps grid system. Put all the divs in a container with `.row` class and mark the ng-repeated div with `.col-sm-4` Add `max-width:` and `overflow: auto` to your container so you get the scrolling.